# Crear trigger que elimine despues de insertar, SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy creando un `trigger` para una tabla que se ejecute cuando se inserte algo en ella y este elimine los datos de la tabla de donde se trajeron los datos.

`current_products` es una tabla, y `finished_products` es otra, esta es la consulta:

```
$query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
(room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
$query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

una vez hecha esta consulta el `trigger` que iría en la tabla `finished products` seria:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELETECURRENTPRODUCT_AI 
AFTER INSERT ON finished_products 
DELETE FROM `current_products` 
WHERE room = 34
```

pero me sale que hay un error de sintaxis cerca de `DELETE FROM`, como puedo hacer?

he intentado también:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELETECURRENTPRODUCT_AI 
AFTER INSERT ON finished_products 
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM `current_products` 
WHERE room = 34
```

Comment: Prueba con CREATE TRIGGER DELETECURRENTPRODUCT_AI ON finished_products AFTER INSERT AS BEGIN DELETE FROM current_products WHERE room = 34 END;

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de BD estás usando? Conviene que pongas la etiqueta respectiva en la pregunta. La sintaxis que estás usando parece incompleta (según qué manejador uses). Por otra parte, no tiene ningún sentido poner un valor a mano, como el `34` en el `TRIGGER`, deberías usar  en este caso `NEW.room`. Finalmente, conviene que digas también qué ocurre: ¿el código da error, qué error?, ¿el código no hace nada?, etc.

Comment: uso sql amigo, uso 34 porque estoy probando primero desde la consola de phpmyadmin para ver la sintxis, pero no funciona, ya uno vez que la consulta funcione le pongo su respectivo valor

Comment: MySQL? SQL Server? Microsoft SQL Server? PosgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? SQLLite?
Todos son SQL.. pero son distintos.

Comment: @AmimM MYSQL :)